# Appending the logged-in User to Django REST framework POST model update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've tried to follow this answer [Django Rest Framework - Post Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256852/django-rest-framework-post-foreign-key) but can't get it to work. A user POSTs the creation of an Event, but I cannot figure out how to configure the serializers to append the User foreign key constraint to associate Event with the User.

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    runtime_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=60, null=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['zone','start_datetime','runtime_seconds','user']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['user'] = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super(EventSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

**views.py**
This feels janky--I making dog out of tee'ing up the merged event and user data but still not sure why it doesn't work.

```
class EventCreateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user_serialized = UserSerializer(request.user)
        payload={
            **request.data,
            **user_serialized.data}
        pprint(payload)
        serializer_event = EventSerializer(data=payload)
        if serializer_event.is_valid():
            pprint(serializer_event.validated_data)
            serializer_event.save()
            return Response(serializer_event.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        pprint(serializer_event.errors)
        return Response(serializer_event.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

*Example*

```
POST
{"id":"fc01ef4c-c05f-4416-ba10-dd0d779abddb","zone":"278c6def-beab-49a2-9876-ce3eef35a16e","start_date":"2021-06-10T06:00:00.000Z","start_time":"1:30 am","start_datetime":"2021-06-10T07:30:00.000Z","runtime_seconds":"333"}
```

*Output--missing user_id*

```
OrderedDict([('zone', '278c6def-beab-49a2-9876-ce3eef35a16e'),
             ('start_datetime',
              datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 1, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Denver' MDT-1 day, 18:00:00 DST>)),
             ('runtime_seconds', 333)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the user inside the `save()` method.

```
serializer_event = EventSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer_event.is_valid():
     print(serializer_event.validated_data)
     serializer_event.save(user=request.user)
     return Response(serializer_event.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Halleluja! That simplified the code a lot.