# Django Rest Framework POST and PUT Foreign Key ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with a model serializer.
My models

```
class ItemState(models.Model):
"""Status for a item"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ItemState, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializer:

```
class ItemStateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemState
        fields = '__all__'


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = ItemStateSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my viewset

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ Item view set """
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrAdmin, )
```

My question is, how can i  do a put or post without create a status object? 
I wanna replace this

```
HTTP PUT 
{
   "title": "example",
   "status": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "hello"
   }
}
```

by this

```
HTTP PUT 
{
   "title": "example",
   "status": 1
}
```

Thanks community!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66192049/305383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two serializer fields for the same model field - one for details, and the other default with the id ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758324/deserialize-post-request-with-subset-of-serializer-fields-in-drf/52783102#52783102)). So in your case, your serializer can be defined as:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status_detail = ItemStateSerializer(source='status', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now your PUT requests will be like you want:

```
HTTP PUT 
{
   "title": "example",
   "status": 1
}
```

but when you GET an `Item`, it will have `ItemState` details in the `status_detail` field:

```
HTTP GET
{
   "title": "example",
   "status": 1
   "status_detail": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "hello"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep the other class or can you get rid of it all together? It seems simpler to do:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # or you can change to int if you want
```

Comment: This is not consistent! Thanks!